# Autopopulate PeoplePicker field from Sharepoint List - Infopath 2013

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I've searched wide and far and am unable to get this to work.

**First, let me describe what I'm going for.**
We have a SharePoint list that has information about services and service focals. The 'Service Focals' element is a People/Group field. Each service has a service focal.

**Now, the InfoPath form:**
I have a form in which the user should pick a Service and on selection, the Service Focal field should be populated. I've already created the data connection to the SP List and have the services populating in a dropdown list box. *However*, I am unable to populate the Service Focal field.

I'm aware on how to use the calculated field and whatnot, but this peoplepicker is really stumping me. I've tried many different things but in the end, the field just doesn't populate.

The end goal is to have this request for service to add an entry to a different list and it will be assigned to the service focal.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Tony

[Form Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfsD4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out for anyone who might run into this problem.

Essentially, all 3 fields under the pcperson need to be defined.
This includes:
- DisplayName
- AccountId
- AccountType

If all of those fields are not set in the peoplepicker control, then the form will not update.

Of course, this needs to be done with an Action rule